# Zend Framework Modules can't find/load Models

Tags: zend-framework, model

For some frustrating reason, I configured some Modules, which seemed to work fine,
However I cannot load a Modules Models. If I move the Models to the Default they load,
but I just can't get the Framework to find them locally..

Example:

My Modules Directory is:

application\modules\books\models\books.php (books is my Model)

```
class Application_Module_Books_Model_Books extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {}
```

I also tried..

Books_Model_Books,  Model_Books, books, Modules_.. you name it I tried it :)

My controller is in the Books Module, and is an Index Controller, and it
can never find the Local Model.

I'm using Application.ini and it is configured this way:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

I have a BootStrap in the Modules Directory:

class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}

I'm on Zend Framework 1.10, and ideas.. ?

Answer (score 5):

What just fixed it for me was to add the following line to application.ini

**resources.modules[]=**

Then i added a Bootstrap.php to the module directory ('application\modules\books\')

```
class Books_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
      $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
           'namespace' => 'Books_',
           'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__)
      ));
      return $autoloader;
     }
}
```

Move the books model to 'application\modules\books\models\Books.php'

```
class Books_Model_Books extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {...}
```

Now you should be able to load the model in the IndexController

```
$model = new Books_Model_Books();
```

Answer (score 2):

In the application.ini, add a simple line:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

and in the method _initAutoload() inside the Bootstrap put:

```
$front = $this->bootstrap("frontController")->frontController;
$modules = $front->getControllerDirectory();
$default = $front->getDefaultModule();

foreach (array_keys($modules) as $module) {
    if ($module === $default) {
        continue;
    }

    $moduleloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => $module,
        'basePath'  => $front->getModuleDirectory($module)));
}
```

make sure the name of models inside each module are like

```
[name_module]_Model_[name_model]
```

in you case, like

```
class Books_Model_Books {
}
```

and that's all :D

Answer (score 0):

The correct class name would be Books_Model_Books, but the filename of that class would need to be Books.php (note the capital 'B').

You shouldn't have a bootstrap in the modules directory, but you probably do want a bootstrap for each module directory, so you'd need a class:

```
class Books_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

at: application/modules/books/Bootstrap.php (again note the capital 'B').

Check the section on the module resource autloader at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html for more info.

Comment: It turns out the problem was my Module Name did not start with a Capital 'M'.. Yikes..

Answer (score -1):

1-feel free to delete this cuz you don't need it any more  :

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

and place this code inside you Bootstrap.php file [application bootstrap ] not the module bootstrap

```
public function _initAutoload()
{
$autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
'namespace' => '' , 
'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules/'));
return $autoloader;
}
```

getting back to config you need also to add

```
   resources.modules[] = ""    
   resources.frontController.defaultModule = "admin"
```

here is my complete config file :

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "news"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = 1
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
;resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "xxxxxx"

resources.db.adapter = "Mysqli"
resources.db.isdefaulttableadapter = true
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname = "xxxxx"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

hopefully i didn't miss any thing