# Zend, cannot find model from the Bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, bootstrapping

I'm trying to put a model into the Zend Registry from the main application bootstrap file:

```
public function _initRegistry()
{
    $this->bootstrap('db'); 

    $processmanager = new Systems_Model_Process();
    Zend_Registry::set('processmanager', $processmanager);
}
```

For some reason, I'm met with the following errors:

```
Warning: include_once(Systems/Model/Process.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/planetxg/public_html/dash/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Systems/Model/Process.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/planetxg/public_html/dash/application/../library:/home/planetxg/public_html/dash/library:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/planetxg/public_html/dash/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Fatal error: Class 'Systems_Model_Process' not found in /home/planetxg/public_html/dash/application/Bootstrap.php on line 20
```

The model in question is in the following location:

```
application/modules/Systems/models/Process.php
```

Is there something simple I'm missing or not setting here at all? I should add everything works fine when calling models normally within controllers.

Here's my main ini block if it helps:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Utilities = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers/Helpers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = 
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "CreativeLaunch_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Systems_"
```

Comment: did you specifiy the modules directory?

Comment: You mean in the application.ini? If so, yeah - I'll add that here too

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542892/zend-framework-modules-cant-find-load-models)

Comment: Does the bootstrap class for the systems module extend `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`? Also, typically, module names (and the directory name) are lower-case, i.e., `systems` rather than `Systems`, though the classname itself will use the `ucfirst()` version `Systems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a module bootstrap class at `application/modules/systems/Bootstrap.php` which extends `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`. This will setup module autoloading. Also your module folder should be lowercase - `application/modules/systems`.

The module resource needs to have run before your `_initRegistry` method in the main bootstrap file, so change the first line of that method to:

```
$this->bootstrap(array('db', 'modules'));
```

Everything else looks good.

Comment: I already had a module bootstrap, just a placeholder with nothing more than the class declaration and extension as you describe. I added the modules call to the bootstrap link but that hasn't changed anything :/ - tried changing the case as well, but nada

Comment: Actually, I just noticed the array wrap around the bootstrap argument, added that and its now working a treat, thanks!